# ¿cómo genero un modelo desde un método?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

tengo una duda, estoy realizando un método para llenar la tabla de un modelo llamado piezasConInfo, estoy agregando unas 3 columnas, necesito crear una lista que luego sera usada en otro método... En estos momentos estoy retornando un objeto genérico pero no veo como crear la lista :/

este es mi método

```
        public List<Pieza> GetInventario() {

        List<Pieza> respuesta = new List<Pieza>();

        var pieza = db.Pieza.FirstOrDefault();
       // var ValorTotal = ValorTotal(pieza.Costo_pieza);
        var cantidadDiponible = CantidadDisponible(pieza.Id_pieza);
        var minimo = false;
        if (cantidadDiponible < pieza.Cantidad_pieza)
        {
            minimo = true;
        }

        var piezaConInfo = new
        {
            Id_Pieza = pieza.Id_pieza,
            Nombre_Pieza = pieza.Nombre_pieza,

            minimo,
            cantidadDiponible

        };

        respuesta.Add(piezaConInfo);

        return respuesta;
    }
```

Comment: Evita crear funciones que retornen objetos genéricos, no es una muy buena práctica.. Lo ideal es que definas una clase para poder hacer un método que devuelva un objeto (o lista) tipada..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si defines una clase

```
public class PiezaConInfo
{
    public int Id_pieza {get;set;}
    public string Nombre_Pieza {get;set;}
    public int minimo {get;set;}
    public int cantidadDiponible {get;set;}
}
```

podrias convertirla directo desde linq

```
public List<PiezaConInfo> GetInventario() 
{
    var result = db.Pieza.Select(x=> new PiezaConInfo()
                                    {
                                        Id_Pieza = x.Id_pieza,
                                        Nombre_Pieza = x.Nombre_pieza,
                                        cantidadDiponible = CantidadDisponible(x.Id_pieza)
                                        minimo = CantidadDisponible(pieza.Id_pieza) < x.Cantidad_pieza,
                                    });

    return result;
}
```

no deberias retornar anonimos

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, pero no queda claro por que no retornar anónimos.

Comment: porque si lo haces deberias devolver un tipo `dynamic` con lo cual no tendras validacion de sintaxis en el codigo al compilar, por eso es recomendable crear la clase que tampoco cuesta tanto

Comment: Buen punto, creo que seria una buena parte de la respuesta ese comentario.